# Display number of records returned in a query

Tags: searchkit, formbuilder

Is there a way to display the number of records returned in a SearchKit query? We would like to have an easy way to see the number of records being displayed in each of our SearchKit reports. Once we put that SearchKit into an afform, it would be helpful for that number to update as we enter information into filters.

An example would be: I have made a query in SearchKit that displays all contacts who have made a contribution to our organization (I am grouping those contacts by Contact ID). When I make a table display of that query, I would like to quickly see how many contacts are being displayed. I then use afform so that I can filter that query based on things like state, country, date range, or contribution amount. Ideally, the number of results would update depending on what filters were set. Is there a way to do this currently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do that.  In the display that you create for the search there's a field at the top - before the list of items to be shown in the search - called 'Show Count' - just check that.  This is in release 5.45, and is in the 'Display' component, not the 'Search Kit' itself.

Comment: we are currently on 5.41.2 right now. I am not seeing that field on the display settings. Do you happen to know if that is a feature on a later release?

Comment: I really don't remember, sorry. I was using Search Kit for a particular application and as Search Kit was evolving I was updating releases almost every month.  Now on 5.45.2 and I think that feature has been there at least for a couple of releases.  To be clearer, I've updated the answer

Comment: We will try running an update and see if that gives us what we need. Thanks for the help.